# How do I do a long listing of files and only show those that are a certain size?

Tags: shell, files, ls

I need to show a long listing of files in a directory but only those that are a certain size in bytes. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find files that are bigger/smaller than x bytes?](http://superuser.com/questions/204564/how-can-i-find-files-that-are-bigger-smaller-than-x-bytes)?

Answer (score 1):

The command you need is:

```
$ find /dir -type f -size 2048
```

where type f defines it if a file
the size argument defines the number of bytes

Comment: Do you mean `find` and not `file`?

Comment: Yes, silly me, I stand corrected.